# How to determine the type of object in blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry-jde, custom-application

On my screen i have ButtonField and CustomButtonField.
Both have been added to Listner of my screen.

myScreen.add(new ButtonField("click me"));
myScreen.add(new CustomButtonField("click me Again"));

Now i want to know which button is clicked and type of object in fieldChanged function.

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

//Here- how to determine the type of object
//which object has been clicked
//ButtonField or CustomButtonField????
}

Kindly Help
Thanks
SIA

Answer (score 0):

```
instanceof is your friend:

public void fieldChange(Field field, int context) {
    if(field instanceof CustomButtonField)
       ;//do something
    else if(field instanceof ButtonField)
       ;//do something
}
```